# What are the exact protocol differences between Azure AD "classic", ADFS "3.0" & B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adfs3.0, azure-ad-msal

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053341/328397) describes the difference between MSAL and ADAL in various use cases and contexts (mobile, non mobile)

What are the exact protocol differences between these implementations?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of protocols that are supported by each of these services?

Comment: @GauravMantri The fact I'm using a custom library, and not a random library, implies that "passport | liveID | Azure AD | B2C" does more than what OIDC specifies.

Answer (score 3):

Azure AD is available both through ADAL which uses the [Azure AD v1 Endpoint](http://aka.ms/aaddev) and through MSAL which uses the [Azure AD v2 Endpoint](http://aka.ms/aadv2).

[Azure AD B2C](http://aka.ms/aadb2c) is accessible via the v2 endpoint but requires that a [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies) be indicated.

There are several differences between these. Your best bet is to compare the docs between the protocols/tokens of each:

- v1 endpoint - [protocol doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) & [token doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)
- v2 endpoint - [protocol doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols) & [token doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens)
- B2C - [protocol doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-protocols) & [token doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens)

Just to name a few differences:

- **v2 endpoint adds an extra `v2.0` to the authorization and token endpoint URLs**, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/**v2.0**/authorize`
- **v1 has a `resource` query parameter** in the request to the authorization endpoint, **v2 and B2C don't**, it puts the resources as extra values in the existing `scope` query parameter. **B2C has the extra `p` query string parameter**
- **The token has several differences including the value of the issuer and the name of some of the basic claims**.
- **v2 doesn't support the on-behalf-of flow yet**. See [v2 limitations doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations) as there are other protocol limitations.