# How to read Azure B2C Custom Attributes with Graph API (works OK with Azure AD Graph)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

As of today the documentation recommends to use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure AD / B2C resources.

Before, with Azure AD Graph API, we could use queries like
[https://graph.windows.net/[tenant]/users/1a2a9c4d-fc59-4fd9-ad14-b72b549cdf6a?api-version=2013-11-08](https://graph.windows.net/%3Ctenant%3E/users/1a2a9c4d-fc59-4fd9-ad14-b72b549cdf6a?api-version=2013-11-08)

and the response included Azure B2C custom attributes (created on Azure portal)

```
{
        "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
        "value": [
            {
                "objectId": "00000eab-603a-4de2-9d25-d3821e7d6583",
                ...
                "extension_3a4189d71ad149c6ab5e65ac45bd6add_MyAttribute1": "something"
            }
        ] 
}
```

This does not happen with the Graph API, only some "basic" attributes are returned
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/00000eab-603a-4de2-9d25-d3821e7d6583

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "00000eab-603a-4de2-9d25-d3821e7d6583",
    ...
}
```

Also tried to explicitly select the property but the extension value is not returned

> ...graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/00000eab-603a-4de2-9d25-d3821e7d6583/?$select=id,extension_3a4189d71ad149c6ab5e65ac45bd6add_MyAttribute1

How can we read Azure B2C custom attributes with Graph API?

Answer (score 4):

Custom attributes are returned:

**Request**

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/8b2ceb5d-4f45-4e42-b979-419119df4eaf?api-version=1.6
```

**Response**

```
{
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
      "objectType": "User",
      "objectId": "8b2ceb5d-4f45-4e42-b979-419119df4eaf",
      ...
      "userType": "Member",
      "extension_5c5668a4ddb44c27b0d55cb412c41787_loyaltyId": "some value from the demo"
}
```

Source: this is from the [sample app: B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet)

---

**Lookup Extension Guid** via the Azure Portal

[image: how to get to azure ad app registrations]

[image: azure ad app registrations]

The above is for builtin in policies.

Comment: They are returned by Azure AD Graph API, not by Graph API. That is the issue.
Azure AD Graph: https://graph.windows.net/[tenant]/users/1a2a9c4d-fc59-4fd9-ad14-b72b549cdf6a?api-version=2013-11-08
Graph API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/00000eab-603a-4de2-9d25-d3821e7d6583

You can use Graph Explorer and try:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Comment: Has the 'new' Graph API been fixed yet?

Comment: Where does the GUID in the 'extension' property come from? I can't see it anywhere in the B2C portal...

Comment: Now graph.microsoft.com also works `/users?$filter=extension_4bcfd51bce4f4a63888880701f4c32d5_GroupId%20eq%20'${loggedInUser.groupId}'`

Comment: @radders it´s your application Id

Answer (score 3):

See this SO post: [As of today, we recommend that you use the Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770376/which-graph-api-should-be-used-with-azure-ad-b2c) https://graph.windows.net to access and manage your B2C tenants

Comment: It also says "Even with those gaps, we strongly recommend that developers start using Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph"

Comment: I know, confusing.  See my exact same comment on Shawn's answer and his repsonse

Comment: While we do recommend developers use Microsoft Graph over AAD Graph, there are still areas where support is not yet available in Microsoft Graph.  We are working to close those gaps.  This is currently documented here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/ together with the gaps.  However, having said that, I cannot repro what you see. I am able to perform a similar request to get extension properties through Microsoft Graph successfully - i.e. GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{upn}?$select=id,extension_{appId}_{extName}`

Comment: Can you add a client request id and timestamp to an "unsuccessful" attempt to retrieve a extension property please?  We might be able to trace why it's not being returned in your case.

Answer (score 1):

So first step is to find in your custom policy:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">...<Item Key="ClientId">**57ff56e7-40a0-43fd-a9a3-8d6c1544bcf4a**</Item>
```

Custom attributes are named `extension_attributename`. To get it through graphql it is required to be like this:

```
extension_{client id of the app NO DASHES responsible for storing extensions }_{attributename}
```

e.g. `extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute`

As you can see this is done also in the code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Helpers/B2cCustomAttributeHelper.cs#L7-L20

```
internal class B2cCustomAttributeHelper
    {
        internal readonly string _b2cExtensionAppClientId;

        internal B2cCustomAttributeHelper(string b2cExtensionAppClientId)
        {
            _b2cExtensionAppClientId = b2cExtensionAppClientId.Replace("-", "");
        }

        internal string GetCompleteAttributeName(string attributeName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeName))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", nameof(attributeName));
            }

            return $"extension_{_b2cExtensionAppClientId}_{attributeName}";
        }
    }
```

example for graph call: **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/3545c38b-3f6b-4a4b-8820-e7f954a86e1e?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute**

Multiple custom attributes at the same time:

**[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-objectid}?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute,extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_myotherattribute,etc](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser-objectid%7D?$select=extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_mycoolattribute,extension_57ff56e740a043fda9a38d6c1544bcf4a_myotherattribute,etc)**

Answer (score 0):

Specifying my tenant in the request path didn't work for me when logged into graph-explorer using the account I created the B2C Tenant with.

I needed to create a user w/an email address of @my-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com. I created such a user, assigned it Global Admin rights, and I was able to use Graph Explorer to get custom attributes for users assigned to the B2C Tenant.

For clarification, I used this option to create a new Member account for the B2C Tenant:
[image]