# Finding and Displaying Extension Properties in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

This AAD powershell easily lists out the extension Properties for a user:

```
> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 50413382@wingtiptoys.com |select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                                                             Value
---                                                             -----
odata.metadata                                                  https://graph.windows.net/d29b7a9b-6edb-4720-99a8-3c5c6c3eeeb0/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element
odata.type                                                      Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime
employeeId                                                      50413382
onPremisesDistinguishedName
thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaEditLink                              directoryObjects/8cc715a1-0698-4d1a-8f49-441a84b6dbc4/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/thumbnailPhoto
thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaContentType                           image/Jpeg
userIdentities                                                  []
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_division             |30103611|50435526|50230396|10192257|86009851
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_company              wingtiptoys Inc.
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute10 GF
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_employeeID           50413382
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_cn                   50413382
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute8  wingtiptoys Inc. Inc.
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute7  Chuck
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute6  US11
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute5  US1-Rochester, NY- Site
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute4  USC
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute2  Regular
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_employeeType         ARR
```

I now have a request to build this sort of display into an authenticated web page, with a prior page that someone can type in that Object ID and see that output on the screen using the Microsoft Graph Client SDK.

The key issue is that I can't hardcode the list of Extension Properties. I need to just list what is on that particular user.

I've found how to get the value of an extension attribute once you know it's name, but how do you get the list of attributes above without knowing the attribute names ahead of time? (the `-ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty` part of the PowerShell)

I've tried to get at this data via graph explorer, and am having difficulty. I've tried:

- `/v1.0/me/?$select=id&$expand=extensions`  (returns an empty extensions element)
- `/v1.0/me/?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes` (returns some of the properties (but not all))

Comment: This link seems to says it's not possible in MS graph sdk. The post is now 6 years old. Is that still true? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641450/custom-attributes-properties-in-aad-finding-them-in-ms-graph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `/beta` endpoint to get the complete property set. The `/v1.0` endpoint has a default filter that gets applied but the `/beta` endpoint does not.

For example (using Graph Explorer):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd
```

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 425 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "givenName": "Adele",
    "jobTitle": "Product Marketing Manager",
    "mail": "AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "18/2111",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Vance",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd"
}
```

Using the beta version:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd
```

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "ageGroup": null,
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 425 555 0109"
    ],
    "city": "Bellevue",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:26Z",
    "companyName": null,
    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
    "country": "United States",
    "department": "Sales & Marketing",
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "employeeId": null,
    "faxNumber": null,
    "givenName": "Adele",
    "imAddresses": [
        "AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
    ],
    "isResourceAccount": null,
    "jobTitle": "Product Marketing Manager",
    "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
    "mail": "AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
    "officeLocation": "18/2111",
    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
    "otherMails": [],
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
    "passwordProfile": null,
    "postalCode": "98004",
    "preferredDataLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
    ],
    "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2017-09-12T21:08:09Z",
    "showInAddressList": null,
    "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime": "2017-09-12T21:08:09Z",
    "state": "WA",
    "streetAddress": "205 108th Ave. NE, Suite 400",
    "surname": "Vance",
    "usageLocation": "US",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "externalUserState": null,
    "externalUserStateChangeDateTime": null,
    "userType": "Member",
    "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_ObjectType": "teacher",
    "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_TeacherNumber": "106",
    "assignedLicenses": [
        {
            "disabledPlans": [],
            "skuId": "c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df"
        }
    ],
    "assignedPlans": [
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "Adallom",
            "servicePlanId": "8c098270-9dd4-4350-9b30-ba4703f3b36b"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "SharePoint",
            "servicePlanId": "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "SharePoint",
            "servicePlanId": "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "exchange",
            "servicePlanId": "efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline",
            "servicePlanId": "0feaeb32-d00e-4d66-bd5a-43b5b83db82c"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "MicrosoftOffice",
            "servicePlanId": "43de0ff5-c92c-492b-9116-175376d08c38"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "YammerEnterprise",
            "servicePlanId": "7547a3fe-08ee-4ccb-b430-5077c5041653"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "RMSOnline",
            "servicePlanId": "bea4c11e-220a-4e6d-8eb8-8ea15d019f90"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "ProjectWorkManagement",
            "servicePlanId": "b737dad2-2f6c-4c65-90e3-ca563267e8b9"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "PowerBI",
            "servicePlanId": "70d33638-9c74-4d01-bfd3-562de28bd4ba"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline",
            "servicePlanId": "3e26ee1f-8a5f-4d52-aee2-b81ce45c8f40"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline",
            "servicePlanId": "4828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "Sway",
            "servicePlanId": "a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "exchange",
            "servicePlanId": "34c0d7a0-a70f-4668-9238-47f9fc208882"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "exchange",
            "servicePlanId": "9f431833-0334-42de-a7dc-70aa40db46db"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "exchange",
            "servicePlanId": "4de31727-a228-4ec3-a5bf-8e45b5ca48cc"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "TeamspaceAPI",
            "servicePlanId": "57ff2da0-773e-42df-b2af-ffb7a2317929"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "PowerAppsService",
            "servicePlanId": "9c0dab89-a30c-4117-86e7-97bda240acd2"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "ProcessSimple",
            "servicePlanId": "07699545-9485-468e-95b6-2fca3738be01"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "Deskless",
            "servicePlanId": "8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "exchange",
            "servicePlanId": "8e0c0a52-6a6c-4d40-8370-dd62790dcd70"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "MicrosoftStream",
            "servicePlanId": "6c6042f5-6f01-4d67-b8c1-eb99d36eed3e"
        },
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:03:25Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "OfficeForms",
            "servicePlanId": "e212cbc7-0961-4c40-9825-01117710dcb1"
        }
    ],
    "deviceKeys": [],
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": null,
        "extensionAttribute2": null,
        "extensionAttribute3": null,
        "extensionAttribute4": null,
        "extensionAttribute5": null,
        "extensionAttribute6": null,
        "extensionAttribute7": null,
        "extensionAttribute8": null,
        "extensionAttribute9": null,
        "extensionAttribute10": null,
        "extensionAttribute11": null,
        "extensionAttribute12": null,
        "extensionAttribute13": null,
        "extensionAttribute14": null,
        "extensionAttribute15": null
    },
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
    "provisionedPlans": [
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "SharePoint"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "SharePoint"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        },
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the   `extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_ObjectType` and `extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_TeacherNumber` in the results.

Comment: This is very helpful, and I can confirm Graphexplorer beta endpoint returns all the data.. I just now need to figure out Graph sdk side.  I may end up just outputting the JSON response, using the Graph sdk to make a raw http call. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library

Comment: You can use the recently release [Beta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet) client. You'll access the extensions from the AdditionalData dictionary. 

`var user = await graphClient.Users["87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd"].Request().GetAsync();`
<p/>

`var dictionaryWithExtension = user.AdditionalData;`

Comment: Thanks! This works Great! you both for your help in answering this. I was struggling to find documentation, or a path forward with all of the different api's and versions.