# Microsoft Graph API - generate the filter query for the extension attribute

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, graphserviceclient

I have create a extension/Custom attribute called `extensions_{b2cextensionappid}_IsDemoAccount` in the Azure AD B2C to flag the user is a demo user.

I have tried to create filter query to select all the demo users in the Azure AD B2C directory using `GraphServiceClient` in dotnet core API. But it is not working.

```
   var result = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            //.Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'test2' and c/issuer eq '{config.Value.TenantId}')")
            .Filter($"Extensions/any(c:c/{IsTemporaryAccount} eq true')")
            .Expand("Extensions")
```

Is there any way to generate the filter query for the extension attribute? I did not find any samples in the Microsoft documentation.

Please provide any solutions or an reference to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you want to achieve? Like what is the end result you are execting.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal The demo account should be live for only 5 days from created time, I have created a service to check and remove the expired demo accounts.
To do this I need to query only the demo accounts from the AD. My AD have more than 50, 000 users.

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The below Graph Query help you to filter based on the custom attribute.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=extension_{b2cextensionappid}_IsDemoAccount eq 'Yes'&$select=extension_{b2cextensionappid}_IsDemoAccount`

You can refer
[Make API calls using the Microsoft Graph SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS)

Answer (score 1):

You confuse [Create extensionProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [Create open extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0).

`extension_{b2cextensionappid}_IsDemoAccount` is actually `extensionProperty` rather than `open extension`.

So you should use the following code to filter users.

```
        var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Filter($"extension_{b2cextensionappid}_IsDemoAccount eq true")
        .GetAsync();
```

Please note the extension property should be `extension_**_**` rather than `extensions_**_**`.