# Sharepoint List fed by Users Profiles in the organization

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, office365api

this is my first post in StackOverflow, I hope I am doing it well, I am beginig with a bit of lowcode/nocode development.
My first task assigned is to create a SharePoint List fed by Office 365 Users, or Graph, or the same Sharepoint Users profile.
But I need to add extra custom attributes as the skills or an about me, the idea is to make a Power Apps Canvas where the user can fill this up and also change their User Profile.
If you can give me a hand with an start point I will appreciate it a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45817185/6271132

Comment: Not really but thanks! I actually found it in the Power Apps forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer thanks to one user in the Power Apps Community forums
[Link here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Populating-Sharepoint-List-Records-with-a-Canvas-App/m-p/1513467)

At the end I used the Office 365 Users connector with Power Apps Canvas, this and the Sharepoint Connector, we created a ForALl to loop into the users, and with a comparison with the Mail column we could update the records and create them in case they are not, else create them.

```
Patch(
    'Org',
    ForAll(Filter(Office365Users.SearchUser(), AccountEnabled=true),
    With({ _rec: LookUp('Org', MailColumn = Mail) },
    {
        ID: _rec.ID,
        Title: DisplayName,
        MailColumn: Mail,
        JobTitleColumn: JobTitle,
        DepartmentColumn: Department,
        Manager: Office365Users.Manager(Id).DisplayName
    }
)
```

Thank you anyway!