# Create user with other mail provider in Azure AD B2C (gmail,etc...)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I used Microsoft Graph API PHP SDK to add user in my Azure Active Directory B2C. I managed to create users with a `userPrincipalName` like `name@mytenantid.onmicrosoft.com`.

I wasn't able to add users with a GMail address such as `john.doe@gmail.com`.

I tried to add the `signInNames` collection but I got the following response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users resulted in a 400 Bad Request
response: 
   { "error": { 
       "code": "Request_BadRequest", 
       "message": "Invalid property 'signInNames'.", 
       "innerError": (truncated...)
```

Here is my JSON request body :

```json
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "userPrincipalName": "john@doe.fr",
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",  
    "passwordProfile" : {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "P@!ssWor?D"
    },
    "signInNames": [
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "john@doe.fr"
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: [Not supported yet, see this SO post, use AAD Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770376/which-graph-api-should-be-used-with-azure-ad-b2c): `https://graph.windows.net`

Comment: i think this functionnality was added in the 1.6 version in july.
Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations (Chapter "Create a user (local account)")

Comment: I suspect that applies to AAD not B2C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing [Microsoft Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io) with the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog). These are two different APIs. While they share a lot of functionality, calls to these APIs are not interchangeable.

The [User object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties)  in Microsoft Graph API doesn't support a `signInNames` property. This is why it is returning that error.

Local account users are not supported by Microsoft Graph API at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone will still have the same problem, in MS Graph Api you can use "identities" instead of "signInNames" and your JSON will look like

```
{
   "accountEnabled":true,
   "displayName":"John Doe",
   "userPrincipalName":"john@doe.fr",
   "creationType":"LocalAccount",
   "passwordProfile":{
      "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":true,
      "password":"P@!ssWor?D"
   },
   "identities":[
      {
         "signInType":"emailAddress",
         "issuer":"<your tenant domain name>",
         "issuerAssignedId":"john@doe.fr"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works.. saved my day after 100 searches.