# Accessing Azure AD B2C Applications using Graph API

Tags: .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant, you have the possibility to create applications that are linked to your tenant.

[image: applications]

It is possible to access you're tenant's objects using Microsoft Graph API.

My question is how can i access (read, create update delete) AD B2C applications using Microsoft Graph API (or Microsoft.Graph nuget package)?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) for how to use Azure AD Graph API in Azure AD B2C . But refer to [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications) , currently it seems doesn't support accessing AD B2C application object programmatically .

Comment: Another [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770376/which-graph-api-should-be-used-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 0):

The applications that are created through Azure AD B2C admin UI are the same as those used by [Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview). These applications cannot yet be created or modified through the Graph API, but you can read and/or search them (using $filter queries) like any other applications with Graph API (e.g. by using the .../applications endpoint in AD Graph API).

Graph API is expected to provide complete CRUD operations in the future, but currently, there is no ETA.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us that must do this with Java, I've been working (well, trying to work) on an api for doing this:

https://github.com/Xitikit/xitikit-blue

Although I'm not sure if you are using Java, this might still help you understand some of the things you may need as well.