# How do I list B2C users (CreationType = LocalAccount) in Microsoft graph?

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I can use the AzureAD Graph to list all B2C users in my tenant like so:

> https://graph.windows.net/{{tenantId}}/users/?api-version=1.6&$filter=creationType eq 'LocalAccount'

However that does not work for `http://graph.microsoft.com.` I don't see a field for B2C in [the graph user object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user). I do see that I could filter for B2B (guest) users with `$filter=userType eq 'Guest'` like I did in azure graph.

I see that [MSFT recommends using the old Azure AD graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770376/which-graph-api-should-be-used-with-azure-ad-b2c) as of 3/17. Is this particular feature one that does not exist yet in Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [you must use Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C tenant, since Microsoft Graph doesn't support a few of the user properties (including the `creationType` property) that are used by Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Also see https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph. Unfortunately this is still a gap that needs to be closed, but I don't have an ETA for this right now.