# Azure AD B2C User not populating correctly when querying using Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am "successfully" querying an Azure AD B2C user via `GraphServiceClient` provided by `Microsoft.Graph` using:

```
var b2cUser = await graphServiceClient.Users[id].Request().GetAsync();
```

The returned user object does not appear to be populated correctly. Nearly all of the properties, including `Id`, are set to `null`. The data I would expect to see within the structure however is contained within in a raw key-value dictionary property called `AdditionalData`.

I was expecting the `GraphServiceClient` to do the work of parsing the JSON returned by the Microsoft Graph API. Is what I am seeing the correct behaviour or should I be using the library differently? I would be happy to be referred to the documentation for `GraphServiceClient` but my googling foo has failed me so far...

If I try to use select like this:

```
var b2cUser = await graphServiceClient.Users[id].Request().Select("id").GetAsync();
```

I get a `System.AggregateException` exception for every field I have tried.

Comment: see [Which Graph API should be used with Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770376/which-graph-api-should-be-used-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: How did you get it to authenticate? I can only authenticate against Azure AD Graph.

Comment: @JamesSouth If you are asking how I authenticated against Microsoft.Graph, I think I used https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample as an example. But it has been a while since I did it. I don't want to send you off on a wild goose chase... To authenticate against Azure AD Graph API, https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet contains working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the .NET client library for Microsoft Graph.

Currently, [you must use Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C tenant, since Microsoft Graph doesn't support a few of the user properties (including the `creationType` property) that are used by Azure AD B2C.

[This Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph article](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph) indicates that the current gap between the Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph APIs for managing users in an Azure AD B2C tenant.