# I cant retrieve existing users in my Azure AD B2C Tenant

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have created Azure AD B2C Tenant and i have 3 members (users) contain in the Azure AD B2C Tenant, but my objective is to show the existing users in the tenent.

I have used the graph.microsoft.com and all the other methods to retrieve the existing users ( including Microsoft tutorials) but i cant retrieve and see the existing users.

Any help would be fine to figure out the way to do it , thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Try to use AAD Graph API instead of Microsoft graph. Microsoft graph has some limitations in AAD B2C user management.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771194/185123

Comment: Thank You for the help @Yang and spottedmahn , with the help of your comment and this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-client-credentials/ i have manage to get the users , but i search link to  make the use of results of users to insert into a asp.net MVC web app , but i was unable to find exmaple, do you have idea how to present the users using asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ambiguous but it is clear from [the Azure AD B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) that "you must use the Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD B2C directory".

I have also experienced issues which getting a few properties, including any extension properties, for users in an Azure AD B2C directory using the Microsoft Graph API.