# MSAL.NET vs ADAL.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, adal, azure-ad-msal

I've been working on implementation SSO in xamarin application and started working with ADAL.NET nuget package. Then I found MSAL.NET. Looking through documentation I haven't found any hints what is more preferable to use in production application. They seem quite similar in the matter of functions yet have different API.

In the roadmap section of documentation is mentioned, that they work on unifying cache structure in order to make upgrade from ADAL.NET to MSAL.NET easier. Does it mean it is better to start working with MSAL.NET and skip studying ADAL.NET as it going to obsolete in a while?

I would appreciate some insight on main differences and preferable library to work with.

**UPD:** found what I was looking for: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Pre-requisite:-Register-your-application-with-Azure-Active-Directory

Comment: Idk much about it but, just in case you flew by this [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053341/5873815). In hope that it can help you.

Comment: @Antry, thank you. Strange I haven't found this question.

Comment: No problem ! I had to take the `.NET` out, people seem to leave it out, the question is also already 18 months old, I've check the Microsoft repository and is still actively being update, good sign. Unfortunately, I don't think I can help you much more than this ^^

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one designated as a duplicate. Lots of developers wonder which library to use (ADAL/MSAL). Here is the [MSAL documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal#differences-between-adalnet-and-msalnet-applications) on selecting which library to use to fit your development needs. Also, here's what's different with the [v2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare). Hope this helps.