# Unauthorized request in Sharepoint API with MSAL token

Tags: azure, sharepoint, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

**Background**
I'm developing a mobile app which authenticate with Azure Active Directory (Microsoft Authentication), and have access to some information in Sharepoint. My first choice was to use Ionic Cordova, but Cordova-MSAL integration seems to be not supported. So we have chosen Xamarin, in order to develop an cross plataform app, but compatible with Microsoft authentication.

**Situation**
I am trying to connect with Sharepoint API.

1- I have registered a new app in Azure (Active Directory), and
        given permissions.

2- I am getting the bearer token with MSAL
        library (in web and with Xamarin), after logging in myself (like in
        the link below):
        https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript

3- Now I'm making the following request to Sharepoint API.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID'),
method: GET
Headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

BUT I'm always getting the following error:

```
{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. No certificate thumbprint specified in token header."}
```

I'm reading a lot of people talking about errors with MSAL, but is the official way (ADAL looks like about to be deprecated).

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I too was facing this issue, when utilizing MSAL.js to authenticate and acquire an access token to make successful calls to the SharePoint Online API.

The following documentation from Microsoft provided an awesome example and explanation of authentication via MSAL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

However, I needed to move forward with utilizing the acquired tokens to call the SharePoint API directly--rather than consuming the services via the Graph API.

To resolve the problem, I had to define my scopes as follows:

```
scopes: [https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/.default]
```

Using the example from the Microsoft article, I made the necessary changes. I was able to utilize the acquired access token to successfully make calls to the SharePoint API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quickstart for MSAL JS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/msal.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to MSAL.js Quickstart</h2><br />
    <h4 id="WelcomeMessage"></h4>
    <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button><br /><br />
    <pre id="json"></pre>
    <script>

    var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "{clientID}",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };

    var sharePointConfig = {
        sharePointFileEndpoint: "https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/{folderName}')/Files('testFile.txt')/$value"
    }

    //the defined scopes were updated for making calls to the SharePoint API.

    var requestObj = {
        scopes: ["https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/.default"]
    };

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    // Register Callbacks for redirect flow
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);


    function signIn() {

        myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
            //Login Success
            showWelcomeMessage();
            acquireTokenPopupAndCallAPI();

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    function acquireTokenPopupAndCallAPI() {
        //Always start with acquireTokenSilent to obtain a token in the signed in user from cache
        myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {

            //Http Request

            callAPI(sharePointConfig.sharePointFileEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // Upon acquireTokenSilent failure (due to consent or interaction or login required ONLY)
            // Call acquireTokenPopup(popup window)
            if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {

                    //Http Request

                    callAPI(sharePointConfig.sharePointFileEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        });
    }


    function graphAPICallback(data) {
        document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    }


    function showWelcomeMessage() {
        var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
        divWelcome.innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + myMSALObj.getAccount().userName + "to Microsoft Graph API";
        var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
        loginbutton.innerHTML = 'Sign Out';
        loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
    }

    function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {

                callAPI(sharePointConfig.sharePointFileEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
            } else {
                console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
            }
        }
    }

    function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
        if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
            return false;
        }
        return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
            errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
            errorCode === "login_required";
    }

    // Browser check variables
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
    var isEdge = msedge > 0;
    //If you support IE, our recommendation is that you sign-in using Redirect APIs
    //If you as a developer are testing using Edge InPrivate mode, please add "isEdge" to the if check
    // can change this to default an experience outside browser use
    var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";

    if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
        if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
            showWelcomeMessage();
            acquireTokenPopupAndCallAPI();
        }
    }
    else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
        document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
            myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
        };
        if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
            showWelcomeMessage();
            acquireTokenPopupAndCallAPI();
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Please set a valid login type');
    }


    function callAPI(theUrl, accessToken, callback) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        /*
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
        */
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        xmlHttp.send();         
    }


    function signOut() {
        myMSALObj.logout();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above example is a modified version of the example from Microsoft. I was able to utilize this for successful testing.

Answer (score 0):

The token is invalid, please check the way you got the access token. I granted `AllSites.FullControl` permission to the app. So the scope should be

```
https://{xxx}.sharepoint.com/AllSites.FullControl
```

The response:

[image]

Comment: Can you please confirm  that using this generated token are you able to access sharepoint data?

Comment: Can you provide reference link from where you have generated token and which authenticatiob flow?

Comment: @anomepani I used code grant flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: @anomepani The token has `AllSites.FullControl` permission.

Comment: Even if token permission if the valid audience is not there in token it will not work.

Comment: @anomepani You are right, the scope should be 'https://{xxx}.sharepoint.com/AllSites.FullControl', just as I said in the answer.

Comment: @TonyJu this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046598/msal-or-adal-library-for-use-with-azure-ad-b2c-and-xamarin?rq=1) says that ADAL (AD v1) is incompatible with Xamarin...

Comment: @AlexAcc Tony means that  var requestObj = {
    scopes: ["user.read"]
};

here the scope should be https://{xxx}.sharepoint.com/AllSites.FullControl 
did you replace that and try ? is it giving the same error ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending that in scope of MSAL, and also as a param in a request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX..." and No Luck

Comment: My problem, when doing a request to login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX.. even in postman, is that I receive the html of "Microsoft Sign In" as raw body response, but no popup opening...

Comment: @AlexAcc Can you provide more details? How did you get the token? The complete request url is?